# Logstash/Grok copy message and other field to create new output format

Tags: logstash, grok

I have the following log in logstash:

```
{
    "message":"{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-26T15:59:25.688Z\",\"v\":0}",
    "@version":"1",
    "@timestamp":"2016-02-26T15:59:35.317Z",
    "beat":{"hostname":"sensu-node-dev","name":"sensu-node-dev"},
    "count":1,
    "fields":null,
    "input_type":"log",
    "offset":83219,
    "source":"/var/log/bunyan/myapp-info.log",
    "type":"log",
    "host":"sensu-node-dev",
    "tags":["beats_input_codec_plain_applied","error"],
    "name":"myapp",
    "hostname":"sensu-node-dev",
    "pid":749,
    "level":50,
    "err":{"message":"Cannot find module 'lol'","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\n    at next (native)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\n    at next (native)\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5","code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND"},
    "msg":"Cannot find module 'lol'",
    "time":"2016-02-26T15:59:25.688Z",
    "v":0
}
```

I would like logstash to output the following:

```
{
    title: "error message from host sensu-node-dev",
    text:"{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"hostname\":\"sensu-node-dev\",\"pid\":749,\"level\":50,\"err\":{\"message\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Cannot find module 'lol'\\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)\\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)\\n    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)\\n    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/app.js:27:6)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:29:5)\\n    at next (native)\\n    at onFulfilled (/srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)\\n    at /srv/www/dev.site/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5\",\"code\":\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\"},\"msg\":\"Cannot find module 'lol'\",\"time\":\"2016-02-26T15:59:25.688Z\",\"v\":0}"
}
```

`sensu-node-dev` is taken from the `host` field in the original log. The `text` field contains what the `message` field in the original log had. It feels like this should be a trivial task.

I've been looking at grok and it isn't beginner friendly at all! I'm not sure whether this should be done in the filter or in the output in my logstash .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new field, even using the values from other fields:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "title" => "error message from host %{host}" }
}
```

You could probably rename the other fields to put them where you want:

```
mutate {
    rename => { "name" => "[text][name]" }
}
```

If there are leftover fields you don't want, you use mutate->remove_field.